# как отправить сообщения и в лс и в беседу?

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, бот

vk_api как отправить сообщения и в личные сообщения и в беседу?

мой код вышел таким, но он не работает:

```
import vk_api
from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotLongPoll, VkBotEventType
from vk_api.longpoll import VkLongPoll, VkEventType
import random

# ------- bot token and connect api ----------
TOKEN = ''
vk = vk_api.VkApi(token=TOKEN)
vkget = vk.get_api()
longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(vk)
ls_longpool = VkLongPoll(vk)
# ---------------------------------------
def send(message):
    if event.from_chat:
        vk.method('messages.send', {'chat_id': event.chat_id, 'message': message, 'random_id': random.getrandbits(64)})
def sendls(message):
    vkget._method('messages.send', {'user_id': event2.user_id, 'message':message, 'random_id':random.getrandbits(64)})

# ------- longpool ---------
for event in longpoll.listen():
    if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:    # это для бесед
        text = event.obj['text']
        send('привет')
    for event2 in ls_longpool.listen():
        if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:       # для ЛС
            sendls('привет')
'''
помогите.
```

Comment: Круто вы от одного токена открываете и `UserApi` и `BotApi`.

Comment: а как надо то??

Comment: подскажите пожалуйста поточнее, я новичок в сфере vk api